# How to make a loading page on nextjs 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, state, loading

Hi im trying to get a loading page to show while website is taking the time to load. as it quite a large website I thought a loading screen would provide the best possible user experience however I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to work on nextjs 13. I have created a simple functional component that says loading... and have imported it directly into my layout.jsx folder.

I am using the app directory method which is quite new and im also new at nextjs so im a little lost  ^^

any advice would be great.

thanks

my layout is as follows

**layout.jsx**

```
import "./globals.css";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import Loading from "../components/loading/loading";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>{children}</Suspense>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**LoadingPage.js**

```
const LoadingPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="loading w-screen h-screen bg-red-100">
      <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoadingPage;
```

**Loading.js**

```
import LoadingPage from "@/components/loading/loading";

export default function Loading() {
  return <LoadingPage />;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the next js 13 they have a new feature called Loading UI. you need to create a file called loading js in same folder. you can find other details here https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/loading-ui

[image]

Comment: Note: Only works for the newest app folder structure

Comment: What If I want to have a loading state for the homepage